# WPF listboxitem contextmenu

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a `ContextMenu` for a `ListBox`. It just should be displayed when a `ListBoxItem` is selected by a right mouse button click. But the `ContextMenu` opens whenever a right click is done in that `ListBox`, even when it's empty.

This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listIn"
             Width="148"
             Height="175"
             Margin="25,52,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=groupid}"
             SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"
             SelectionMode="Extended" />
    <ListBox Name="listOut"
             Width="148"
             Height="175"
             Margin="335,52,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             MouseRightButtonDown="ListBoxItem_MouseRightButtonDown"
             SelectedItem="listBox2_SelectionChanged"
             SelectionChanged="listBox2_SelectionChanged"
             SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="update" />
                <MenuItem Header="delete" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Name="cmdRein"
            Width="75"
            Height="23"
            Margin="215,75,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="button1_Click"
            Content="moveRight" />
    <Button Name="cmdRaus"
            Width="75"
            Height="23"
            Margin="217,0,0,145"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="button2_Click"
            Content="moveLeft" />
    <Button Name="button1"
            Width="59"
            Height="23"
            Margin="0,14,330,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="button1_Click_1"
            Content="Load" />
    <TextBox Name="textBox1"
             Width="83"
             Height="23"
             Margin="25,15,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   <ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                      <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here your Adding `ContextMenu` for `ListBox`. This `ContextMenu` will opens when you right click on the `Listbox` itself.. If you need the `ContextMenu` for `ListBoxItem` alone, initialize `ContextMenu`  for `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: you mean like this?                                    <ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="update"/>
<MenuItem Header="delete"/>
</ContextMenu>
</ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>                                           if I do this, I'm getting the message:                              Error 1 The attached property 'ListBoxItem.ContextMenu' is not defined on 'ListBox' or one of its base classes. C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication4\WpfApplication4\MainWindow.xaml 23 14 WpfApplication4

Comment: Not like that, You need to give this in the `ListBoxItem`. How your adding the Items to `ListBox`?

Comment: ok, now I've made this:                                                          
<ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="update"/>
<MenuItem Header="delete"/>
</ContextMenu>
</ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
and there isn't en error message again, but it still isn't work. Data will be added by the 'load' button.

Comment: I'm getting the value of a textfield, make a database search and fill it into the ListBox:                                                   try
{
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
listeAnwaerter.Items.Add(myReader[0].ToString() + "," + myReader[1].ToString());
}
}
catch (Exception e21) { Console.WriteLine(e21.ToString()); }

Comment: Check the updated ans, where i have removed the ItemsSorce from the another ans and it will work for your case.

Comment: I have one more question... is it possible to set the text color of an item when added?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an ItemTemplate for the ListBox like:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                          <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The ItemsSource *Item* is an `ObservableCollection<string>`